# HTML Compression with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, compression

I've been looking and have been unable to find any information on how to do this.

I have a decent amount of HTML and as the page I'm creating generates HTML and *all* the css within the `style` attributes, it gets a bit big. What I need is a javascript method to compress my html by removing any and all unnecessary white space.

I've tried using regex but not only did that not work (at least how I did it). Spaces aren't a big problem, it's mainly all the new lines. What I tried:

```
html = html.replace(/\t|\r|\n/g, '');
```

But as I'm no expert with regex, this didn't work.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: By the time the document is ready and you're able to compress the HTML with javascript, it's already loaded, so it would make no difference ?

Comment: Have you tried with `/\t|\r?\n|\r/g`

Comment: @adeneo You don't understand. I'm making a generator. It spits out HTML and it's got a tonne of white space. Before I spit it all out I want to filter out all of the white space.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan How exactly would you include tabs to that? It works but I noticed tabs in the output like this: `</p>        </div>      </div>    </div>  </div>`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Scratch that. They were 2 spaces indentation so I got them removed just by added another `html=html.replace()`